Existing resource loop output to array
I am currently deploying a number of resources into an existing Azure subscription. As part of the deployment, I want to get the IDs of a list of existing application security groups, store those IDs in an array, then pass that array to different modules.
I have the following code setup to try this:
main.bicep
// Get existing ASG IDs
resource existingAppSecGroups 'Microsoft.Network/applicationSecurityGroups@2024-01-01' existing = [for AppSecGroup in AppSecGroupNames: {
  name: AppSecGroup
  scope: resourceGroup(netRg)
}]

output appSecGroupIds array = [for (AppSecGroup, i) in AppSecGroupNames: {
  AppSecGroupId: AppSecGroup[i].id
}]

module deployKeyVaults 'modules/keyVaults.bicep' = {
  scope: resourceGroup(resourceGroups[0])
  name: 'deployKeyVault'
  params: {
    location: location
    appSecGroupsIds: appSecGroupIds
  }

then in the module, reference the specific appSecGroup using the index:
keyVaults.bicep
param appSecGroupsIds array

// Define Key Vaults to be deployed
param keyVaults array = [
  { 
    name: 'keyVault01'
    appSecGroups: [
      appSecGroupIds[0]
      appSecGroupIds[3]
    ]
    }
  }
]

Whenever I try and reference the output 'appSecGroupIds' in the main.bicep keyVault module params, I get the error 'The name "appSecGroupIds" does not exist in the current context'.
The only way I seem to get this close to working is to pass the invidual ASG IDs to the module from the existing resource loop and not the output array, for example:
main.bicep
// Get existing ASG IDs
resource existingAppSecGroups 'Microsoft.Network/applicationSecurityGroups@2024-01-01' existing = [for AppSecGroup in AppSecGroupNames: {
  name: AppSecGroup
  scope: resourceGroup(netRg)
}]

module deployKeyVaults 'modules/keyVaults.bicep' = {
  scope: resourceGroup(resourceGroups[0])
  name: 'deployKeyVault'
  params: {
    location: location
    existingAppSecGroupId0: existingAppSecGroups[0].id
    existingAppSecGroupId3: existingAppSecGroups[3].id
  }

then in the module, reference the specific appSecGroup using the index:
keyVault.bicep
param existingAppSecGroupId0 string
param existingAppSecGroupId3 string

// Define Key Vaults to be deployed
param keyVaults array = [
  { 
    name: 'keyVault01'
    appSecGroups: [
      existingAppSecGroupId0
      existingAppSecGroupId3
    ]
    }
  }
]

Is what I am trying to achieve possible, if so, what is it I am doing wrong? Or is there a better way I can achieve this?

you should define appSecGroupIds as a variable if you wanna use the value in the same template: var appSecGroupIds = [for (AppSecGroup, i)...


Existing resource loop output to array

The approach you tried will not work as youre using ASG alone. For this configuration to work as expected we need include subnet configuration and ASGs. It was because we cannot map ASG directly.
This will enforce different access policies for various resources within the same subnet, or if you reqiuire dynamic management of resuorce access based on attributes.
main.bicep:
@description('Location for all resources')
param location string = resourceGroup().location

@description('Resource Group for Networking')
param netRg string = 'keyVaultRg'

@description('Name of the virtual network')
param vnetName string = 'myVnet'

@description('Name of the subnet')
param subnetName string = 'mySubnet'

@description('Name of the Application Security Group')
param asgName string = 'myAppSecGroup'

@description('Name of the Key Vault')
param keyVaultName string = 'tessamoekv'

resource vnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2023-04-01' = {
  name: vnetName
  location: location
  properties: {
    addressSpace: {
      addressPrefixes: [
        '10.0.0.0/16'
      ]
    }
  }
}

resource subnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets@2023-04-01' = {
  parent: vnet
  name: subnetName
  properties: {
    addressPrefix: '10.0.1.0/24'
    delegations: [
      {
        name: 'myDelegation'
        properties: {
          serviceName: 'Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups' 
        }
      }
    ]
    serviceEndpoints: [
      {
        service: 'Microsoft.KeyVault'
        locations: [
          location 
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

resource asg 'Microsoft.Network/applicationSecurityGroups@2023-04-01' = {
  name: asgName
  location: location
  properties: {}
}


resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2023-02-01' = {
  name: keyVaultName 
  location: location
  properties: {
    sku: {
      family: 'A'
      name: 'standard'
    }
    tenantId: subscription().tenantId
    accessPolicies: []
    networkAcls: {
      bypass: 'AzureServices'
      defaultAction: 'Deny'
      ipRules: []
      virtualNetworkRules: [
        {
          id: resourceId(netRg, 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', vnetName, subnetName) 
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  dependsOn: [
    vnet
    subnet
    asg 
  ]
}


output asgId string = asg.id
output vnetId string = vnet.id
output subnetId string = subnet.id
output keyVaultId string = keyVault.id 

Deployment:


Refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/application-security-groups
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/configure-asg-private-endpoint?tabs=portal
Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults - Bicep, ARM template & Terraform AzAPI reference | Microsoft Learn
